# SQL Server - convert UTC to EST (include Daylight Savings, when appropriate)

Tags: sql-server, timezone

I have a table that stores the transaction date time in UTC time zone. I would need to convert this time to eastern time zone i.e. EST or EDT, depending on the transaction date.

How can I do this without writing a big function or creating a table / view that flags EST / EDT for each transaction date?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which changes the timezone of a value to the relevant time there, and observes Daylight Saving:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),'2021-09-07T15:25:37+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS Sep21,
       CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),'2021-01-09T15:25:37+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS Jan21;
```

Which returns the following:

```
Sep21                              Jan21
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
2021-09-07 11:25:37 -04:00         2021-01-09 10:25:37 -05:00
```

Comment: Also see [this Rob Farley article](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-plan/at-time-zone) and [a follow-up](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/t-sql-queries/using-at-time-zone-to-fix-an-old-report).

Comment: But, if you have to deal with multiple time zones (now or maybe in the future), a "big function or table/view" is actually the easier approach. I have a series on that here: [part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server-part-1/) | [part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3174/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server-part-2/) | [part 3](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3175/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server-part-3/). Creating a table to support business requirements shouldn't be some task to fear.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The CONVERT function returns the time with the offset value (-04:00) as well. I need my final time value without offset. I removed the offset from the input date and I tried to use ```datetime``` instead of ```datetimeoffset``` and also tried to add another style parameter to CONVERT function call ```SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-07 15:25:37', 20) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS Sep21``` but still getting offset value in the output.

Comment: @Neha As Rob explains in the article I posted, if you don't include an explicit offset like Larnu suggested, you need to let SQL Server know that the _source_ time zone is UTC some other way, e.g. `SELECT Sep21 = CONVERT(datetime, (CONVERT(datetime, '20210907 15:25:37') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'));`. This returns `2021-09-07 11:25:37.000` which I think is what you're after, as shown in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=935f71ee19249f36fbbe824a61cb9c59).

Comment: @Neha The offset in the answer here is merely attached to the output, to indicate the destination time zone by specifying the offset (whether DST is in place or not). But you can easily either ignore it at presentation time or convert the output to datetime to explicitly remove it. [For example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab95987c688e3043ff91d7510b7ef5bf).